# Segmentation fault: shared_ptr

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr

I encounter some strange behavior with shared_ptr and I can not explain why this happens:

```
std::shared_ptr<QueryQualification> qualification = query->getQualification();
if (qualification != nullptr) {
    // add selection
    std::shared_ptr<Operator> selection = std::shared_ptr<Operator>(new Selection(qualification));
    selection->setLeftChild(scan);
    ...
}
```

And here is the constructor of Selection which causes the segmentation fault:

```
class Selection : public Operator {
public:
   Selection(std::shared_ptr<QueryQualification> qualificiation) : qualification(qualification) { }
...
private:
   std::shared_ptr<QueryQualification> qualification;
};
```

I know, that I can improve the copy behavior with move semantics here, but I want to get some running code first.

The code above raises a segmentation fault in the constructor of Selection:
[image: The backtrace of the error]

SelectionOperator.hpp (line 24) is the code line of the Selection constructor above.

I really don't understand what is happening here as the qualification object is perfectly valid before giving it to Selection as an argument.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is query null at this point?

Comment: No, query is valid as well. You can see that because std::shared_ptr<QueryQualification> qualification = query->getQualification(); would already lead to a segmentation fault otherwise.

Comment: What does `query->GetQualification()` return? A `shared_ptr`, a `unique_ptr`, an owning raw-pointer which you should `delete`, or a non-owning raw-pointer?

Comment: it returns a shared_ptr.

Comment: Place some asserts just before you access each shared ptr.

Comment: Does `Operator` have a `virtual` dtor? Anyway, why didn't you allocate that object (and create the `shared_ptr`) with `make_shared`?

Comment: yes, Operator has a virtual dtor. Is there any difference in using make_shared?

Comment: Yes, `make_shared<T>(...)` is potentially more efficient than `shared_ptr<T>(new T(...))`, because it can coalesce the two allocations (and corresponding deallocations).

Comment: There seems to be a typo in spelling `qualificiation` in the constructor

Comment: I think @davidc has the answer. Note the spelling of the constructor parameter - qualifi**cia**tion. Your code ends up self-initializing the `shared_ptr` data member in the initialization list. Your compiler should've warned about the unused parameter. If it didn't, make sure you turn the warning level up.

Comment: It would help to distinguish the parameter `qualification` from the class variable `qualification` by using a modified form of the name, such as `m_qualification` for the member variable

Comment: @davidc It might improve readability, but it's not necessary; in `qualification(qualification)` the first name is unambiguously a member name, and the second takes from the current scope where the parameter name shadows the member. It will still do the right thing, even if it is confusing to read. **Edit:** Missed the misspelling, of course that will cause problems. :)

Comment: You are awesome guys ! ;) And I am pretty stupid :) I would have never found that bug

Comment: so where exactly was the bug here?

Answer (score -1):

```
class Selection : public Operator {
public:
   Selection(std::shared_ptr<QueryQualification> qualification) : m_qualification(qualification) { }
...
private:
   std::shared_ptr<QueryQualification> m_qualification;
};
```

Comment: Because this small mistake is not the reason why the error occurred.